# Xcode not detecting any NeXTSTEP / Foundation / Cocoa classes (no auto-complete)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I just created a new project, created my first file, and started typing. Very shortly I noticed auto-complete wasn't working and syntax highlighting wasn't working:

[image]

Is there some build flag I need to set or some header I need to include in order for this to work? Even something as simple as `NSObject` isn't auto-completed or syntax highlighted.

I'm very new to Xcode, so step-by-step instructions would be preferred.

### Update

So the issue has resolved on its own, but I wish I had a better understand of why.

Normally at work, at the end of the day, I shut down my Mac and go home. The next morning I come in and turn my Mac back on. Last night I took my Mac home and worked from home. Because I worked from home, I left my Mac on overnight and didn't shut it down until the following morning when I came in to work.

Upon coming in to work, auto-complete and syntax highlighting were both fixed. Per one of the senior iOS developers at my work:

> When Xcode isn’t auto completing for me it’s either ‘indexing’ for eternity, i have code that’s broken or I’ve done something like mangled a project file manually and it didn’t seem to reload correctly.

My guess is that Xcode needed 8 or more hours of uninterrupted processor time to index everything (I'm a new iOS developer and this is my first time using Xcode, so it never had time to build indexes before) and by turning my Mac off at the end of every day I was interrupting the indexing process. By leaving it on overnight, it was able to finish.

That's my guess, at least. I wish I knew more, but the issue literally fixed itself.

Comment: Answering and voting to close is not illegal, but it's discouraged and it's sort of pointless. The close vote means "this question should never have been asked". By implication, it shouldn't be answered either — it should be deleted. One shouldn't confuse Stack Overflow with "my blog recording my mysterious adventures with Xcode". On the other hand, if you like your answer, don't vote to close your question: accept your own answer (in 48 hours) and thus "close" the Q&A cycle.

Comment: @matt You can't delete a question that has an answer (trying to gives a pop-up saying "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it.") On the one hand I do think there's merit in the question existing, since others may have the same issue. On the other hand, it's not an issue that can be solved (short of waiting) - so it does no good to post an "answer". Besides, if people are just going to down-vote my answer, it's not like anyone will take it seriously when they have the same issue and stumble upon this.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have opened up a playground rather then a project, try using a project, see if it makes a difference

Comment: Actually I just cropped the screenshot to what I felt was relevant. It was an entire project (I can update the screenshot) created using `pod lib create`. Although a good suggestion.